Insight into heating
Am in Ireland. Hi, looking for some insight into heating and recommendations for a renovation. I live in a small 2 bedroom second floor apartment where the whole block's heating is electricity only. Each apartment, from the day they were built in the 80's has a combi-boiler to heat the water radiators (normal radiators) and the water for shower and dishes.
The radiators are old and a pipe leading to one has leaked which lead to me taking the radiator off to fix it. A plumber that was in to turn off the water (management company rules) and he recommended ripping the pipes out and using electric radiators which sounds good if it would be similarly efficient. The apartment below us did a renovation and did this.
A lot of the discussion online is about comparing gas central heating vs electric radiators which obviously isn't relevant to us so it's hard to know would it be an improvement in cost or in yearly running costs (heating costs and radiator management)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

...have you looked at heat pumps lately?

"A lot of the discussion online is about comparing gas central heating vs electric radiators which obviously isn't relevant to us"
How is it not relevant? Looks to me that's exactly what you're talking about doing - replacing your combi-supplied rads with electrical ones.
That aside, using electricity to simply heat things up is almost always much more expensive than using gas.

@SiHa: ... Unless the electricity is being used to run heat pumps, which can be considerably more efficient than gas. Whether they're less expensive to run depends on utility costs, of course.

Why don't you talk to the people below you and ask their experience?

@keshlam yes, that's what I meant by "simply heat things" - resitive heating, specifically excluding heat pumps. I could've been clearer, I guess! I can't conceive of a world where electric rads could cost less to run than a modern effificient boiler

There are three main ways of heating a home in much of the world. (Yes, there are other things such as solar and geothermal, but for most people these are the choices.)

Resistive electric heat - a.k.a, "toaster". This is by definition more expensive to run than heat pumps and in most places more expensive than gas/oil. But the up-front costs are extremely low, provided you already have sufficient electric service. Note that an electric boiler as you have now is really the same thing, just attached to lots of expensive equipment to actually distribute the heat.
Burn stuff to heat air or water. This includes natural gas and oil used to either heat air ("forced air furnace" -> "air vents") or water ("boiler" -> "radiators"). It is very efficient (typically 90% or more with modern systems, and systems from a couple of decades ago typically 80%). In most places (i.e., where electricity rates are not unusually low or gas/oil prices unusually high) this is less expensive than resistive electric heat to run. Initial costs are high due to the equipment involved. In addition, if you switch modes (e.g., boiler/radiators to forced air) then there is a lot of work involved which gets expensive. These systems also have the disadvantage of burning fuel, with all the issues associated with that.
Heat pump. This is a "reverse air conditioner" in basic concept. It uses electricity to transfer heat from one location to another - in heating mode to transfer heat from outside to inside. While heat pumps do have limits, they can easily be twice as efficient as resistive electric heat while not directly burning stuff. Heat pumps can easily be installed to replace central forced air systems. I don't know if there are any practical examples yet of heat pumps to replace central boiler/radiator systems. Heat pumps can also be installed with a large outdoor unit and multiple small indoor units (multi-head mini-split).

The key to heat pumps is that they are so efficient that with typical gas/oil and electricity prices they are sufficiently more efficient than gas/oil burning systems that they are cheaper to run (unlike resistive electric heat) than gas/oil, which also means that even if utility electricity is produced by burning stuff the overall environmental impact is lower than burning stuff directly yourself.
Because heat pumps are so much more efficient than resistive heat, it is likely that you can install a heat pump for your home without needing an electrical upgrade. What systems are available and the costs of those systems vary tremendously around the world. But that's what you want to look at to replace your electric boiler.

Resistive electric heat is not always the most expensive, it depends on your local utility rates. I live in an area where much of the electricity is generated by hydroelectric dams and electrical heating is much cheaper than gas heating.

@DJ It can be less expensive than gas/oil, depending on market factors. But it is guaranteed to be more expensive to run than a heat pump.

Wasn't questioning the efficiency of heat pumps - just your statement that electric heat is always the most expensive

Thanks for the comments! Great help. Thanks

Have you considered modern high heat retention storage heaters, heated overnight on cheap rate electricity?  They can offer a significant saving over electric panel heaters run on standard rate electricity.  They warm up overnight, and release it during the day.  Modern ones are programmable to release the heat when you want it the most.
You would then have to have a water tank for hot water.  Maybe either one large tank where the old boiler was.  Or separate small ones where you need hot water.

Thanks. A good suggestion. The block doesn't run on a smart electric meter though so electricity costs are the same all day, not cheaper at night. I've heard other people saying they didn't like them when they actually put the storage heaters in despite them seeming like a great option when they were researching it. Thanks for the advice!
